# From 1 to 100, print "ping" if multiple of 3, "pong" if multiple of 5, or else print the number

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I just came home from a job interview, and the interviewer asked me to write a program:

It should, count from 1 to 100, and print...

If it was multiple of 3, "ping"
If it was multiple of 5, "pong"
Else, print the number.

If it was multiple of 3 AND 5 (like 15), it should print "ping" and "pong".

I chose Javascript, and came up with this:

```
for (x=1; x <= 100; x++){
    if( x % 3 == 0 ){
        write("ping")
    }
    if( x % 5 == 0 ){
        write("pong")
    }
    if( ( x % 3 != 0 ) && ( x % 5 != 0 ) ){
        write(x)
    }
}
```

Actualy, I left very unhappy with my solution, but I can't figure out a better one.

Does anyone knows a better way to do that?
It's checking twice, I didn't like it.
I ran some tests here at home, without success, this is the only one that returns the correct answer...

Comment: If you don't want to check it twice use `else if` instead.

Comment: `else if` where? I tried didn't work correctly

Comment: This is the classic FizzBuzz programming question, designed to weed out programmers who can't program: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html

Comment: No need to be unhappy, I think you passed. The object of this test isn't to be elegant, the object is to get working code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your solution is quite satisfactory IMHO. Tough, as half numbers are not multiple of 3 nor 5, I'd start the other way around:

```
for (var x=1; x <= 100; x++){
    if( x % 3 && x % 5 ) {
        document.write(x);
    } else {
        if( x % 3 == 0 ) {
            document.write("ping");
        }
        if( x % 5 == 0 ) {
            document.write("pong");
        }
    }
    document.write('<br>'); //line breaks to enhance output readability
}​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7tXuP/9/)

Also, note that any number other than `0` and `NaN` are truthy values, so I've removed the unnecessary `!= 0` and some pairs of parenthesis.

---

Here's another version, it doesn't make the same modulus operation twice but needs to store a variable:

```
for (var x=1; x <= 100; x++) {
    var skip = 0;
    if (x % 3 == 0) {
        document.write('ping');
        skip = 1;
    }
    if (x % 5 == 0) {
        document.write('pong');
        skip = 1;
    }
    if (!skip) {
        document.write(x);
    }
    document.write('<br>'); //line breaks to enhance output readability
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7tXuP/10/)

Comment: Not that different from mine, but still better, as I asked for. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I've thought about it in many ways but all the simple logic ones require 2 checks. I've only added an `else` micro-optimization, as I said, your code is pretty satisfactory IMO. Sec I'll attempt to redo it in a single line of code, but that'd probably get you reproved. `=]`

Comment: @BernaMariano updated answer, now it doesn't make the same calc twice, however it requires a variable.

Comment: This is one line ;) : `for (var x=1, skip; x <= 100; x++, skip=0)     
        ((x % 3 || document.write('ping') || (skip=1)) &&
        (x % 5 || document.write('pong') || (skip=1)) &&
        skip || document.write(x)) + document.write('<br>');`

Comment: @Shmiddty Yup, that `<br>` really helps to read the output. I kept it separated from the main logic as the question didn't ask to print new lines. Adding the `<br>` makes it much more readable though. `=]`

Comment: @Shmiddty That's a clever way to declare and reset the `skip` flag, nicely done. `=]`

Comment: I wonder if you get extra points for minifying by hand: `for(var x=1,s,d=document,t=3,f=5;x<101;x++,s=0,t=x%3,f=x%5)((t||d.write('ping')||(s=1))&&(f||d.write('pong')||(s=1))&&s||d.write(x))+d.write('<br>');​`

Comment: And one step further because I can! `for(var x=1;x<101;x++)document.write((((x%3?'':'ping')+(x%5?'':'pong'))||x)+'<br>');​`

Answer (score 9):

Here's my one-liner:

```
for(var x=1;x<101;x++)document.write((((x%3?'':'ping')+(x%5?'':'pong'))||x)+'<br>');
```

​
I'm using ternary operators to return either an empty string or `'ping'/'pong'`, concatenating the result of these operators, then doing an OR (if the number is neither divisible by 3 or 5, the result of the concatenation is `''` which is FALSEY in javascript). When both cases are true, the result of the concatenation is `'pingpong'`.

So basically it comes down to

```
'' || x         // returns x
'ping' || x     // returns 'ping'
'pong' || x     // returns 'pong'
'pingpong' || x // returns 'pingpong'
```

Comment: +1, may not the most practical, but beats all and any JS minifier. `=]`

Comment: Good one, but I think you would NEVER think of this standing in front of a board, with a pen and 5 senior developers waiting for your solution...

Answer (score 6):

The best solution I came up with is this one:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var message = '';
  if (i%3 === 0) message += 'ping';
  if (i%5 === 0) message += 'pong';
  console.log(message || i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which allows for a dynamic list of multiples without adding more conditionals.

```
// List of outputs
var outputs = [
    {mult: 3, str: 'ping'},
    {mult: 5, str: 'pong'}
    // {mult: 10, str: 'play'} ex: [30] => 'pingpongplay'
];

// Loop 100 times
for (var i = 1, j = 100; i <= j; i += 1) {

    // Set empty vars
    var result, string = '';

    // Loop through the listed output objects
    outputs.forEach(function (output) {

        // If listed multiple, concat string
        if (i % output.mult === 0) {
            string += output.str;
        }

    });

    // Set result
    if (string.length) {
        result = string;
    } else {
        result = i;
    }

    // print result
    document.body.innerHTML += result + '<br>';
}
```

And as a function which passes jslint:

```
/*jslint browser: true */
var printOutputs = function (array, iterations) {
    'use strict';
    var i = 1;
    var outputResults = function (arr, idx) {
        var result;
        var str = '';
        arr.forEach(function (item) {
            if (idx % item.mult === 0) {
                str += item.str;
            }
        });
        if (str.length) {
            result = str;
        } else {
            result = idx;
        }
        return result;
    };
    while (i < iterations) {
        document.body.innerHTML += outputResults(array, i) + '<br>';
        i += 1;
    }
};
var outputs = [
    {mult: 3, str: 'ping'},
    {mult: 5, str: 'pong'}
];
printOutputs(outputs, 100);
```

And for fun, a minified ES6 version:

```
const pO=(arr,itr)=>{let i=1,o=(a,idx)=>{let r,s='';a.map(v=>{if(idx%v.mult===0)s+=v.str});s.length?r=s:r=idx;return r};while(i<itr){document.body.innerHTML+=`${o(arr,i)}<br>`;i++}};
pO([{mult:3,str:'ping'},{mult:5,str:'pong'}], 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a few variations on this (using `fizz` and `buzz`) as a benchmark to consider different ways of iterating over conditional logic.

`while` won again:

```
// Iterate using a recursive function
// firing a callback once per iteration

function f(s,n) {
    if(++n >= 102) return;
    s === '' ? console.log(n-1) : console.log(s);
    !!(n % 3)
        ? !!(n % 5)
            ? f('',n) : f('Buzz',n)
        : !!(n % 5)
            ? f('Fizz',n) : f('FizzBuzz',n);
}

// Iterate using a `while` loop
// firing a callback after satisfying a condition

function b(n) {
    var i = n;
    $:
        while(++i) {
            if(i % 3)
                if(i % 5) 
                    console.log(i);
                else 
                    console.log('Buzz');
            else if(i % 5) 
                console.log('Fizz');
            else 
                console.log('FizzBuzz');
            if(i >= 100) 
                break $;
        }
    return;
}

// Iterate using a `for` loop
// firing a callback once per iteration

function F(n) {
    var i = n, f = 'Fizz', b = 'Buzz', o = '';
    for (; i <= 100; i++) { 
        o = !(i % 3) 
            ? !(i % 5) 
                ? f + b : f 
            : !(i % 5) 
                ? b : i; 
        console.log(o);
    }
    return;
}

// Iterate using a `for` loop
// firing a callback after satisfying a condition

function B(n) {
    var i = n;
    var fiz = 'Fizz';
    var buz = 'Buzz';
    for(; i <= 100; i++)
        if(!(i % 3))
            if(!(i % 5))
                console.log(fiz + buz);
            else
                console.log(fiz);
        else if(!(i % 5))
            console.log(buz);
        else
            console.log(i);
    return;     
}


f('', 1); // recursive
b(0);     // `while`
F(1);     // `for`
B(1);     // `for
```

**Benchmark: http://jsperf.com/fizzbuzz-mod**

Comment: Update: After more tests on different browsers, the third method is starting to pull away from the others in terms of operations-per-second. The outlying difference being that it 'deduces' first by running through all logic, and then firing a single callback. Interesting to note.

What I'd be interested in seeing (if someone is up for it), is an example using inverse loops (e.g. `while(i--)`) to see if it's any more performant.

Comment: before I saw this code I didn't understand why does everyone so pissed about ternary operator

Comment: @ganqqwerty lol yeah i was having too much fun with that in 2013... ive since eased off such syntactic madness, however, now that react/functional style is popular it's making quite a comeback in front-end xD

Answer (score 0):

```js
//create a for loop to count from 0 to 100
       for (let num = 0; num <= 100; num++){
        /**As the count increments, if the number is divisible by 3 and divisible by 5
        print FizzBuzz, I have concatenated the number with FizzBuzz for clarity. 
        Use % instead of \ to ensure it returns an int instead of float.**/
         if ((0 == num % 3) && (0 == num % 5)){
           console.log ("FizzBuzz" + " " + num); 
//otherwise, if the number is divisible by 5 print Buzz
         } else if (0 == num % 5) {
          console.log("Buzz" + " " + num);
//Also, if the number is divisible by 3 print Fizz
         } else if (0 == num % 3){
           console.log("fizz" + " " + num);
         } else {
//meanwhile, still print all the numbers that don't satisfy the conditions above
           console.log (num);
         }
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 for( int number = 1 ; number < 100 ; number++ )
    {
        boolean shouldPrintNumber = true;

        System.out.println("\n");
        if( (number%3) == 0 )
        {
            System.out.print("ping");
            shouldPrintNumber = false;
        }
        if( (number%5) == 0 )
        {
            System.out.print("pong");
            shouldPrintNumber = false;
        }

        if( shouldPrintNumber )
        {
            System.out.print( number );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for var a = 1; a <= 100 ; a++
{
  if a % 3 == 0 && a % 5 == 0
  {
    println("Fizzbuzz")
    continue
  }
  if a % 5 == 0
  {
    println("Buzz")
    continue
  }
  if a % 3 == 0
  {
    println("Fizz")
    continue
  }
  else
  {
    println(a)
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for **why** it does so.

Answer (score -2):

To get rid of the last condition you might use `continue`:

```
for (x=1; x <= 100; x++){

    if( x % 3 == 0 ){
        write("ping")
        continue
    }
    if( x % 5 == 0 ){
        write("pong")
        continue
    }

    write(x)
}
```