# trying to put in a command that will divide #'s divisible by 3,5, & 15

Tags: javascript

Trying to get the code to divide by 3,5,& 15. Keep getting syntax error.

```js
//dividing by three

var pingpong = function(number) {
        var threenumbers = ['3,6,9,12'];
        var bythree = [];
        threenumbers.forEach(function(number) {
        bythree.push(number / 3);
      {
        var fivenumbers = ['5,10,15,20'];
        var byfive = [];
        fivenumbers.forEach(function(number){
        byfive.push(number / 5);
        var fifteennumbers = ['15, 25, 30, 36'];
        var byfifteen = [];
        fifteennumbers.forEach(function(number) {
           byfifteen.push( number / 15);
               };
```

how do I get it to run the code and divide it by the numbers?

> uncaught syntax error?

Comment: Your braces don't match

Comment: indent your code always

Comment: I know this, Im asking where the braces aren't matching and where to fix them.

Comment: Use an editor with auto-indenting.. it will show you. In any case, for `forEach` call(s) is missing a parenthesis, and probably likewise below that. There is also a spurious `{` that will do nothing but add confusion.

Comment: threenumbers.(forEach(function(number) {
    bythree.push(number / 3);
  });

Comment: This doesnt look right

Comment: unless i leave an open parenthesis at the end?

Comment: & now javascript is saying unexpected token by the forEach

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845437/from-1-to-100-print-ping-if-multiple-of-3-pong-if-multiple-of-5-or-else-p ?

Comment: your array should hold numbers not strings, i.e. change `['3,6,9,12']` to `[3,6,9,12]`

Comment: I suggest you write your program one line at a time, building up its functionality very gradually, and making sure at each point that it is both valid syntactically, and also does what you expect, even if in the early stages that's nothing more than printing out 1+1 or regurgitating some input.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you want to happen but ...
1- the data in the arrays `threenumbers` `fivenumbers` and `fifteennumbers` are strings not number.
2- as said in 1 the arrays have one string each so using `forEach(function(number){` will iterate one time setting `number` to "3,6,9,12" "5,10,15,20" "15, 25, 30, 36".
3- you had a bunch of parenthesis open but not closed.

```js
var pingpong = function(number) {
 var threenumbers = [3,6,9,12];
 var bythree = [];
 threenumbers.forEach(function(number) {
        bythree.push(number / 3);
  var fivenumbers = [5,10,15,20];
  var byfive = [];
  fivenumbers.forEach(function(number){
   byfive.push(number / 5);
   var fifteennumbers = [15, 25, 30, 36];
   var byfifteen = [];
   fifteennumbers.forEach(function(number) {
    byfifteen.push( number / 15);
   });
  });
 });
}
pingpong(40);
```

this doesn't yell errors at you but also probably doesn't do what you want as I said I really dont know what you want

Comment: could someone say why i got down voted, constructive critic is good